# How to initialize a dict file code from empty file?

Tags: python

I have a question about generating a `list` with python.
What I need is a file. Each line should contain a string of 12 characters that are randomly created.

An example of the output per line would be:

```
A4lbf4JILv8s
A4lb44Jyuv8m
Am5bf4JhLv89
```

Is it possible to create something like this with python?

If yes, can someone sent me some code which is able to this?

Comment: What does your question have to do with dicts? What is the input and what does it look like?

Comment: @John What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

`string.ascii_letters` contains all ascii letters and `random.choice` gives us a random element in a collection. So we generate as many random characters as we need and stick them together with `str.join`. You should look up any other langauge elements that you're not familiar with in the python documentation.

```
import string
import random

if __name__ == '__main__':

    output_name = '/path/to/my/file.txt'
    num_lines = 20
    num_chars = 12


    output_str = '\n'.join(
        ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for _ in xrange(num_chars))
            for _ in xrange(num_lines)
    )

    with open(output_name, 'r') as f:
        f.write(output_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and instead of 5, set your line numbers:

```
import string
import random

l = list(string.ascii_lowercase) + list(string.ascii_uppercase) + list('0123456789')

with open('filename.txt', 'w') as f:
    for lines in range(5):
        s = ''.join(random.sample(l, 12))
        f.write(''.join(random.sample(l, 12))+'\n')
```